# Make [csdm] and [android-c2dm] synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

There is the tag [c2dm](/questions/tagged/c2dm) used within 83 entries and the tag [android-c2dm](/questions/tagged/android-c2dm) used within 329 entries.

What is the proper approach for this?

Answer (score 3):

If you have enough reputation in the tags [suggest a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-c2dm/synonyms)

If you don't have enough reputation (creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in the tag), post a question here on Meta requesting that a high rep user or moderator create the synonym. You've effectively done this here.